# Get data from related tables, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

some fields tables City

```
create_table "cities", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "name"
```

some fields tables Order

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "count"
t.integer "first_city_id"
t.integer "last_city_id"
```

model Order

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :city, inverse_of: :city
end
```

model City

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :orders, inverse_of: :order
end
```

working output data from Order in view

```
<% @order.each do |orders| %>
<p> <%= orders.count %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Method in controller

```
def edit
@orders= Order.all
@order=Order.where(:user_id == current_user)
end
```

How to get the value from the name Sity table if first_city_id or last_city_id in the Order table contains id required entry of City Table?

Comment: try `current_user.orders` if you defined correct association in user model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup the order associations as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_city, class_name: "City" # it would use first_city_id as the foreign key by default to access city table
  belongs_to :last_city, class_name: "City"
end
```

Getting the first/last city name from an order becomes easy:

```
@order = Order.first

@order.first_city.name
@order.last_city.name
```

If you want to get the first/last city name from an order list, you should use `includes` or `joins` to avoid the n+1 query:

```
@orders = Order.includes(:first_city, :last_city)

<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <p> First City: <%= order.first_city.name %> </p>
  <p> Last City: <%= order.last_city.name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
@orders = Order.
  joins("LEFT JOIN cities AS first_cities ON first_cities.id = orders.first_city_id").
  joins("LEFT JOIN cities AS last_cities ON last_cities.id = orders.last_city_id").
  select("orders.*, first_cities.name AS first_city_name, last_cities.name AS last_city_name")

<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <p> First City: <%= order.first_city_name %> </p>
  <p> Last City: <%= order.last_city_name %> </p>
<% end %>
```

You can get more information and helps from these two docs "[RailsGuides - Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)" and "[RailsGuides - Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)".